I am a Windows user and audioplayers gives linux error
I am a Windows user. Today I updated flutter and an error occurred in the audioplayers package. I could not understand the reason for the error. I am using Windows but I did not understand what the Linux package has to do with it. The error is below. Can you help?
Package audioplayers:linux references audioplayers_linux:linux as the default plugin, but the package does not exist, or is not a plugin package.
Ask the maintainers of audioplayers to either avoid referencing a default implementation via platforms: linux: default_package: audioplayers_linux or create a plugin named audioplayers_linux.
I did flutter clean and pub get but the problem persists
